# too much recursion scheme javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, scheme

I'm using a scheme interpreter in javascript

I'm getting the error "too much recursion" when I try this code:

```
;;;basic things
(define map 
  (lambda (f l) 
    (if (null? l) l 
        (cons (f (car l)) (map f (cdr l))))))

(define filter 
  (lambda (p l)
    (if (null? l) l 
        (if (p (car l))
            (cons (car l) (filter p (cdr l)))
            (filter p (cdr l))))))

(define accumulate 
  (lambda (op initial sequence)
    (if (null? sequence)
        initial
        (op (car sequence)
        (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence))))))

(define reduce 
  (lambda (op sequence)
    (accumulate op (car sequence) (cdr sequence))))

(define append 
  (lambda (l1 l2)
    (if (null? l2) l1
        (append (cons (car l2) l1) (cdr l2)))))

(define make-list 
  (lambda (n f l)
    (if (= n 0) l
        (make-list (- n 1) f (cons (f n) l)))))

(define make-list2-
  (lambda (f n1 n2 l)
    (if (> n1 n2) l
        (make-list2- f (+ n1 1) n2 (cons (f n1) l)))))
(define make-list2 (lambda (f n1 n2) (make-list2- f n1 n2 null)))
(define identity (lambda (x) x))
(define randomitem (lambda (l) (nth (ceil (* (random ) (length l))) l))) 
;;;

(define random0to3 (lambda () (floor (* 4 (random )))))

(define moverandom (lambda (this) (move this (random0to3 ))))

(define searchforcreature 
  (lambda (this cx cy)    ;search only for neighbor tiles
    (begin (define y (make-list2 identity (- cy 5) (+ cy 5)))
         (define L (map (lambda (x) (map (lambda (y2) (cons x y2)) y))
           (make-list2 identity (- cx 5) (+ cx 5))))
        (define L2 (reduce append L))
        (define listoftiles (map (lambda (x) (tile-from-pos (car x) (cdr x))) L2))
        (define listoftiles2 (filter identity listoftiles))    ;remove the falses you get from trying invalid positions
        (define listofcreatures (filter (lambda (x) (and (creature? x) (not (= x this)))) (map topthing listoftiles2)))
        ;(pairtostring listofcreatures)
        (if (null? listofcreatures)
            #f
            (car listofcreatures)))))

(define update 
  (lambda (this world) 
    (begin
      (define target (searchforcreature this (creature-x this) (creature-y this)))
      (begin (print target)
      (if target
          (attack this target)
          (moverandom this))))))
```

but with 10 instead of 5 in the searchforcreatures function,
that means I create a list of 400 items, then map them with the tile-from-pos function
but when I tested the same function in drScheme it ran fine, is it because javascript doesn't optimize for recursion?

my game where you can test the above code:
thesamesite/textarea.html

the main code for the game, in scheme:
thesamesite/env0.sc

Comment: Please don't link to your code in future. Also, I may have broken the tabbing somewhat...

Answer (score 2):

Scheme implementations are required to optimize tail calls such that the recursion executes in constant space.  Most likely, assuming your code is tail recursive, the Javascript based 'interpreter' isn't doing that optimization.  [Actually, likely given that the optimization would be done during compilation and less likely during interpretation.]

Comment: how do I make it do the optimization? here it is: http://schemerobots.comlu.com/lispy.js

Comment: It can't do tail call optimization.

Comment: when I try the same code in http://repl.it/ it doesn't give an error, but gives the right result, so aren't they optimized?

Comment: Some 'interpreters' do compilation and then execution.  Apparently repl.it uses BiwaScheme and the source for BiwaScheme seems to indicate that it performs compilation.  Specificially, in src/system/compiler.js, at the very top, is a function called `is_tail` where the compiler determines if a function is a tail called.  That likely explains why your code works.  Check mark please.

Comment: so maybe if I copy what biwascheme does it will work? but I find it too confusing :S